# How can I replace text value in XML using a SELECT query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have following XML stored in XML column in a SQL Server database

```
<FRUITS>
    <FRUIT> APPLE1234 </FRUIT>
    <FRUIT> APPLE3456 </FRUIT>
    <FRUIT> ORANGE123 </FRUIT> 
</FRUITS>
```

I have a select query:

```
SELECT 
    FRUITS.Value('(FRUITS/FRUIT)','nvarchar(max)') as FRUIT
FROM 
    BASKET
```

Expected result:

```
APPLE_FRUIT1
APPLE_FRUIT2
ORANGE_FRUIT1
```

How to replace the values in the select query?

Comment: your xml got eaten by the editor

Comment: Thank you so much marc_s. I am a new user and was struggling with the format errors. thanks for saving my time.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    xc.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    dbo.BASKET
CROSS APPLY
    XmlContent.nodes('/FRUITS/FRUIT') AS XT(XC)
```

This should give you the expected output.

It works by creating a "list of XML fragments" for each `<FRUIT>` element, and then extracting the contents of that XML element in the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Yes I am using the above format. Since this is an example i did not use cross apply. But my requirement is to change the value directly in the SELECT query. Is that possible?

Comment: @Hari: I quite honestly don't understand .... what do you mean by *change the value in the SELECT* ?? You want to output something other than what is in the column itself? Or what do you mean???

Comment: Yes, I want the output which is different from what is in the column. APPLE1234 --- > APPLE_FRUIT1, APPLE3456 --- > APPLE_FRUIT2, ORANGE123 -- > ORANGE_FRUIT1